# Why does this.props.onLayout not exist for my React Native component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have the following class in my React Native app (using Typescript):

```
class Component1 extends React.Component<IntroProps, {}> {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    console.log(props.onLayout)
  }
  ...
}
```

I read in the documentation on the `View` class that any `View` or component that inherits from it have `this.props.onLayout`. However, this logs `undefined`, and if I use `this.props.onLayout` instead of `props.onLayout`, it gives the warning "Property 'onLayout' does not exist on type 'Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode;>' ".
I've seen other examples of people using `this.props.onLayout` in their component similar to mine, except that mine uses TypeScript.

What I Want To Know:

Why can't I access `this.props.onLayout` here, and how can I access it?

Answer (score 0):

the `onlayout` belongs view, you can use as the following code:

```
class Component1 extends React.Component<IntroProps, {}> {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
   <View onLayout={this.props.onLayout} style={[{},this.props.containStyle]}>
      <Image source={{ uri: 'http://fillmurray.com/200/200' }} width={200} 
     height={200} />
      <Text>My Picture</Text>
    </View>
  }
  ...
} 
class Example extends Component {
  //this is a method
  onLayout = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      width: e.nativeEvent.layout.width,
      height: e.nativeEvent.layout.height,
      x: e.nativeEvent.layout.x,
      y: e.nativeEvent.layout.y
    })
  }

  render (
    <Component1  onLayout={this.onLayout} containerStyle={width:this.state.width}/>
  )
}
```

you can look at this [article](https://medium.com/@ericchurchill/the-react-source-code-a-beginners-walkthrough-i-7240e86f3030), in some content, it show the React.componet source code and analysis it. Actually,React.component is a fuction.

```
function ReactComponent(props, context, updater) {
  this.props = props;
  this.context = context;
  this.refs = emptyObject;
  // We initialize the default updater but the real one gets injected by the
  // renderer.
  this.updater = updater || ReactNoopUpdateQueue;
}
```

the more you want to learn, you can look at the article and read the source code.

Comment: Yep, I've seen this code. The problem is the outermost component in my render() method isn't a <View>, so the onLayout method you're referencing doesn't exist. Any idea what I could do about this? Wrapping the whole thing in a View doesn't work either.

Comment: I update the answer, the basic view like `Text`,`TextInput` also have `onLayout`, the React.Component mainly controls the LiftCycle and composes the component which has views.